# Absolute path import failling with Parcel and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, parceljs

I'm trying to import a local TypeScript module without relative path, that is, something like `app/Foo` instead of `./Foo`. It works in the IDE; Visual Studio Code doesn't report anything, but when I run Parcel it fails:

> Failed to resolve 'app/BaseResolution' from './src/Main.ts'

Main.ts

```js
import BaseResolution from 'app/BaseResolution';
import KeyboardSettings from 'app/KeyboardSettings';
import Preloader from 'app/scenes/preloader/Preloader';

class Main {
    // ...
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["*", "src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

How I run Parcel debugger:

```bash
parcel watch --dist-dir wwwroot/res/js/build src/Main.ts
```